# Tuning parallel GC for efficient Young GC

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

This chart shows the heap utilization (OU+EU+S1U+S2U) of our Java app over 4 days. Each drop is a Young GC event. As you can notice, there's an increasing pattern in the heap usage. Full GC happens after running for 6 days (not shown in chart). Its bringing down the heap usage back to normal levels, but the pause time is 2 mins and it causes the App to drop many transactions.

[image]

Our JRE is 8 and we use Parallel GC. Heap params are as below:

```
 java -server -Xms64g -Xmx64g -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1g -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true
```

I'm trying to understand what tuning is possible to make Young GC more effective, so that it removes all garbage and avoid promotions to tenured generation.

Comment: When you succeeded making minor GC to remove all garbage, then you made it to major GC, with the corresponding duration. As the duration of the major GC mainly depends on the heap size, you probably can't gain much by tuning it. I'd suggest to try `-XX:+UseG1GC`, which was designed to keep pauses low. In Java 11, there's ZGC, and "in some Linux distributions, Shenandoah is available within the OpenJDK binaries" for Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be objects are being promoted to tenured space and then dying. One way to reduce this is to make the young space larger however this will only delay the full collection.

An alternative might be to reduce the heap so it collects more often, reducing the pause time. If you use a 32GB heap, it can use compressed oops making memory usage more efficient.

Comment: Insightful. If we make young space larger, could it retain these tenuring objects in Young space itself and collect it during Young GC?

Answer (score 1):

As Mr. Lawrey points out you can make the young generation larger, which will increase (hopefully) the time between minor GC events.  By doing this, more objects should become garbage and will be collected in the minor GC and not get promoted to the old gen.  An alternative approach is to increase the tenuring threshold, which has the same effect of keeping objects in the young generation for longer.

The other question to ask yourself is, do you really need to use parallel GC?  If you use G1, some of the work of collecting the old space is handled concurrently with application threads.  You might be able to eliminate the long pauses completely (assuming you did not suffer excessive fragmentation of the heap) as you would not require a full compacting collection.

To completely eliminate pauses I can heartily recommend the C4 collector in Zing from Azul (who I work for :-) ).